# Does Apache Camel support Html 5 Server Sent Events?

Tags: apache-camel, server-sent-events

I currently have a polling html consumer that polls a http endpoint every 5 seconds. This works fine.

I need to now support a http endpoint that has SSE as the transport mode. The server will push every 3 seconds or so and I was hoping that camel could somehow handle this. In this case I am the consumer and I have the Server end point I wish to consumer from.

Any thoughts how I could do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could certainly do this in Camel/Servlet as SSE is an HTTP protocol with a specific content-type, so you'd need something like this in your route.

```
<setHeader headerName="Content-Type">
    <simple>text/event-stream</simple>
</setHeader>
```

You'd have to be careful about scale though as I imagine you'd get a new thread for each connection.